# How do I change the 'state' in a StatefulWidget class but from an external function?

Tags: flutter, dart

how do I change the 'state' in a StatefulWidget class but from an external function?

Examples are as follows:

in **lib/main.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'increment-count.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}
```

I want to move the _incrementCounter function to another file. for example in `'lib/increment-count.dart'`.

in **/lib/increment-count.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void _incrementCounter() {
  setState(() {
    _counter++;
  });
}
```

but the `setState` instead displays an error *"The function `setState` isn't defined"*.
can anyone help?

Comment: Why you want to move that function to a different file ?

Comment: Perhaps you should use something else not setState. You can read about [state management](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple). Also read about [BLoC](https://bloclibrary.dev/#/)

Comment: @MidhunMP I think if an application is large and has many functions, it will be easier to read if some of these functions are separate from the parent class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Moving function in another file in this example has no point but here is the solution. Obviously it is a great idea for a bigger function which you want to reuse somewhere else

in your new file increment-count.dart add this

```
int incrementCounter(int counter) {
  return counter + 1;
}
```

and then call it in your main class

```
 onPressed: () => setState(() {
      _counter = incrementCounter(_counter);
    })
```

However answer to your question, how to setState from external function, is not possible.

Answer (score 2):

your'e getting this error `"The function setState isn't defined"` because the second file is no stateful widget which can take up a setState function. and if you then want to increment the counter you have no access, as it is marked as private and the logic part is in a different file.

Than BloC pattern or providers is what you need. Since I'm also still beginner, I can recommend you using providers, as it is quite easy to learn and it does exactly what you want.

https://pub.dev/packages/provider

with this you can like globally define this function and use it in different files.

This can look like this for example (`toggleCounter()` would be the global function then):

```
final counterIncrement = Provider.of<Data>(context).toggleCounter();
```